# How can I deduce that named rvalue references should be treated as lvalues, using [expr]/7?

Tags: c++, expression, language-lawyer

In [expr]/7 we can read:

> In general, the effect of this rule is that named rvalue references
>   are treated as lvalues and unnamed rvalue references to objects are
>   treated as xvalues; rvalue references to functions are treated as
>   lvalues whether named or not.

I wonder how can I deduce from this rule, that named rvalue references should be treated as lvalues? By the way, I believe the text is referring to [expr]/7 when it uses the term `this rule" above.

Comment: The actual rule is in [expr.prim.general]/8, which governs the value category of *id-expression*s.

Comment: Evaluating any reference produces an lvalue. The specific term "rvalue reference" describes the kind of values that can bind to such a reference.

Comment: @T.C. I failed to find anything related to the fact that a named rvalue reference is treated as an lvalue in [expr.prim.general]/8. Could you clarify? I'm talking about N4527.

Comment: In that note (5\7) they give you just a summary of other rules in the Standard (5.1.1\8; 5.2.2\10; 5.2.9\1 etc.) how rvalue references are analyzed by the implementation. You can notice: if such a reference is denoted by an _identifier_ or something similar, that will be an lvalue - according to 5.1.1\8, etc., and if not - it will be an xvalue. [Bingo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTtjvbAvsys&t=1m00s)?

Answer (score 0):

In N4527, to which you refer, you can find the rule in [expr.prim.general]/8:

> An *identifier* is an *id-expression* provided it has been suitably declared (Clause 7). [ ... ] The type of the expression is the type of the *identifier*. The result is the entity denoted by the identifier. The result is an lvalue if the entity is a function, variable, or data member and a prvalue otherwise.

So the name of a variable is always an lvalue even if the declared type is rvalue reference. And if you're in class scope and referring to a non-static data member with declared type rvalue reference, the part about data members applies; you get an lvalue in that case as well.